# Upgrading sonarqube from 8.9 to 9.9 LTS were our current jenkins & application teams are using java 8 , facing error after upgrade to 9.9LTS

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, devops, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

```
Sonarqube stage is failing in jenkins declarative pipeline, were as current sonarqube 9.9LTS requires jdk 17 for sonar scanner, our application teams are using 8 and it will fail the jenkins jobs and jenkins also run on same java 8 

However, it worked with below configuration 




stage('Sonarqube Analysis'){
                when{
                    expression { params.Env == 'DEV'}
                    }
                    tools {
                            jdk "JDK-17" 
                        }
                environment{
                
                    scannerHome = tool 'sonar-scanner-4.8.0'
                }
```

Instead of updating every job is there is any alternate option were we can configure from jenkins so that there will be no issues to the application team to change in every job

Comment: Keep in mind that the JDK versions are different due to many reasons. There are chances that the applications could not be even compiled on a newer JDK version.

Comment: yes for only sonarscanner , in the sonarqube stage we can mention jdk 17 , but for that every application team needs to modify the jobs, any alternate option were we can configure from jenkins or server side for sonarcanner to take jdk-17

Comment: I don't think so. The only option that wouldn't require modification of the pipelines seems to be installation of the corresponding JDK versions to the build agents. But that could be a more challenging task in some environments.

Comment: yes 

then only option is every application team needs to make changes in  there sonarqube  job configuration right?